# Cannot assign ActiveRecord Attributes in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to assign values of ActiveRecord attributes within my models, but for whatever reason, I can't set them.

For instance, I have an AccountModel and this has an Attribute `name`

If I set it from the controller or the console (like `user.name = "John"`), everything works fine.
But, if I try to set it from within the model, like

```
def set_name(new_name)
  name = new_name
end
```

then it doesn't work. On the other hand, retrieving the name, like

```
def get_name
  name
end
```

works just fine. Am I missing something?!
I am using Ruby 2.0.0-p247 and Rails 4.0.0; Please note, that this examples aren't real world examples, I just tried to keep them simple to clarify my problem.

Best regards,
Mandi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def set_name(new_name)
  self.name = new_name
end
```

You need to use the `self` keyword to refer to your instance attributes on assignment. Otherwise ruby will assign your new name to a local variable called `name`.

You might want to `save` your changes after

```
user = User.new
user.set_name('foo')
user.save
```

Take a look at the example [here](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/self-in-ruby), there is one similar to your question at the end ;)

Comment: Did you add the `self` keyword ? it's here on purpose :)

Comment: Ok, now it is working, but I definitely tried that before! Do you have any idea, why the self-keyword is necessary in this case?!

Comment: Yes, it's explained in my answer :) Glad my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, but are you saving the changes? Try adding a save call:

```
def set_name(new_name)
  self.name = new_name
  self.save
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do self.save, just call save inside your model. You only use self.attribute when you need to assign.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    def set_name(new_name)
      self.name = new_name
      self.save!
    end
```

Then call the instance method from controller simply

```
user.set_name('foo')
```