# Is there a gotcha in the behavior of GlobalID based ActiveRecord objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-activejob

It's entirely possible that I am doing something wrong but!

Here's the story. I have a standard, beginners'-level, RoR setup (4.2) with ActiveJob jobs.

One of my jobs calls a method on the record that's been passed in which is intended to modify that record. Pretty normal so far. It looks something like this:

```
class GenericScraperJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(record)
    # perform job with record data
    record.update_myself!
  end
 end
```

And then the `update_myself!` method looks like this:

```
class RecordInDb < ActiveRecord::Base
   def update_myself!
       thisis_a_column = newvalue
       self.save!
    end
 end
```

Now here's the mystery - when I run tests, and check that `fixture_instance.thisis_a_column` is `newvalue`, the test passes. When I start my app, and see what happens in the database, it is *not* updated as expected.

BUT if I say `self.thisis_a_column = newvalue`, then it works correctly everywhere.

I am sure I reloaded my fixture... I did it like this: `fixture_instance = RecordinDb.find(fixture_inst.id)`

It is as if the binding inside the ActiveRecord instance changes, depending on when it was instantiated. Inside my tests, it looks like symbols are being treated as possible messages to send to `self` but in the job, they are being treated as local names. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that `update_myself!` as you have written it works in any context. Are you sure it is only failing for the job and not elsewhere? I suspect there is a problem with your test that is giving you a false positive.

You are encountering a common gotcha in Ruby itself; this is not specific to ActiveJob or even to Rails.

Basically, when Ruby sees this:

```
thisis_a_column = newvalue
```

It assumes that you are declaring a new, locally-scoped variable named `thisis_a_column`.

If you want to assign a value to the column managed by ActiveRecord, which is an instance-level method, you **must** explicitly use `self`, like this:

```
self.thisis_a_column = newvalue
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17991720/4625365

Comment: Gah. My eye didn't catch that I had typed in `assert` instead of `assert_equal` :( So sorry.